# Start search after 3 characters typed in selectize.js single item select

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

In [Selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) single item select, a search is started after the first character is typed into the select box.

I need the search to not start until after inputing three characters in the search box.

Can any one suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In Selectize demo examples you can find this line:

```
if (!query.length) return callback();
```

You can change that to:

```
if (query.length < 3) return callback();
```

As example, in my case where I get form Ajax call some "car/vechicles" list:

```
jQuery('#select-car').selectize({
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'title',
    searchField: 'title',
    options: [],
    load: function(query, callback) {
    if (query.length < 3) return callback(); //if (!query.length)
    $.ajax({
        url: 'search/',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            car: query,
        },
        error: function() {
            callback();
        },
        success: function(res) {
            callback(res);
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('text').onkeyup = function(){
     if(document.getElementById("input-tags").value.length > 3)
     {
         $('#input-tags').selectize({
           // ....Enter Your Code....
         });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with just using query length `if (query.length < 3) return callback();` is when you remove all character from input and retype, it doesn't work because the options are already populated.
Try the following and you will be good to go.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#formid').keyup(function(){
        var len = $(this).find('div.selectize-input.items input').val().length;
        if(len < 3){
            $('.selectize-dropdown.js_client_search').css('display','none');
        }else{
            $('.selectize-dropdown.js_client_search').css('display','');
        }
    });
});
```

then call your selectize

```
$('.js_client_search').selectize({
        load: function(query, callback) {
            if (query.length < 3){
                return callback();
            }else{
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'search/',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        car: query,
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        callback();
                    }, 
                    success: function(res) {
                        callback(res);
                    }
                 });
            }
```